# Adding UIVisualEffectView to the part of UIView with unknown size

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am having a bit of a problem when trying to add UIVisualEffectView to my custom UIView.

[here's the picture of current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDUA0.png)

It now looks like this. The reason for this is, because I have specified 
`frostySection = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))` like this.
I am having trouble because one needs to specify the `visualEffectView.frame` which is in my case unknown until i make the constraints for the parent view.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var container: UIView!
    var featuredImageView: UIImageView!
    var frostySection: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupContainer()
        setupFeaturedImage()
        setupFrostySection()
        layout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupContainer() {
        container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        container.backgroundColor = .cyan
        container.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

    func setupFeaturedImage() {
        let image = UIImage(named: "paradise.jpeg")
        featuredImageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        featuredImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        featuredImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        featuredImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        featuredImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

    func setupFrostySection() {
        frostySection = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
        frostySection.backgroundColor = .clear

        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        visualEffectView.frame = frostySection.bounds
        visualEffectView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        visualEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        visualEffectView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        visualEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        frostySection.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    }

    func layout() {
        container.addSubview(featuredImageView)
        container.addSubview(frostySection)
        addSubview(container)

        container.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(400)
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
        }

        featuredImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
        }

        frostySection.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(110)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```